# Is there a secure PGP signed blogging service

Tags: anonymity

i have a question that was hard to google, so excuse me for asking it here.

Suppesed Alice wants to run a Blog securely. She wants to blog about something she is interested in, but she does not want her Identity to be revealed, because she mabe blogs about world politics, cryptography etc. So she could use WordPress or something via tor and register via a tormail-Adress.

But what if she wants to show Bob what she has been writing on the blog and proof trustworthy persons that she has been writing this blog? Is there a Blogging service where the people can subscribe their articles via a PGP key?

And what if she wants to show Eve that she wrote the Blog Articles A, B and C, but not that she wrote the Article D?

Is there a blogging service where she can create a Key for every post (without regitering multiple times)? And where she can proof individualy that she wrote every article without revealing, that she wrote all of her articles?

Thank you.

Comment: While [resource requests are off-topic on Stack Exchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), I think this question is probably okay if it's understood as, "What kind of scheme would make this possible, and has it been implemented anywhere?"

Comment: Create keys manually, sign the plaintext posts and post them with the signature. As long as the formatting doesn't interfere, anyone should be able to copy/paste the text and verify the signature on his end. In the end, it's still text and the blogging service doesn't know nor care that it's signed/encrypted.